# Java dynamic label controll

Tags: java, dynamic, label

How can i do this better?

```
label1.setText("foo");
label2.setText("foo");
label3.setText("foo");
label4.setText("foo");

For example like(PSEUDOCODE):
for(i=0; i<5; i++;){
label+i.setText("foo");
}
```

I have to change 135 labels so would like some tips over here..
If you also know how to do a function like this easier,..
jlabelnum could be 1,2,3,..135 forex. Label(jlabelnum) -> Label1, Label2,...

```
public void setLabelforView(int jlabelnum, String StringValue, Color color) {
       Label.

        switch(jlabelnum){

           case 1:
               break;
           case 1: 
               break;
           case 2: 
               break;
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you should be using [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Yep, maintain the labels in array or List for easier management and updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deal with many labels create an array of them like this

```
public class Test{

//create the array
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[100];

public Test(){
  //loop through them and set their text value
  for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    labels[i] = new JLabel("foo");
  }
}
```

Then here's a function that would change one of them the text (and color)

```
public void setLabelforView(int jlabelnum, String StringValue, Color color) {
  labels[jlabelnum].setText(StringValue);
  labels[jlabelnum].setForeground(color);
}
```

This function would change all of them

```
public void setAllLabelsForView(String string, Color color){
  for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    labels[i].setText(string);
    labels[i].setForeground(color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer for my problem this will solve it. Thnx for the code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way, from this point, is to use a `HashMap` to index all the components in your form, by name:

```
HashMap<String,Component> map = new HashMap<String,Component>();
Component[] comps = getComponentPane().getComponents();
for (int i=0; i < comps.length; i++)
    map.put(comps[i].getName(), comps[i]);
```

After that, you'll be able to look components up in your `map`, and do what you want with them. If you know you'll only need to mess with the labels, you can check whether each component is `instanceof JLabel` before deciding whether to add it.

(A better approach would be to create the labels programmatically, and with the right text in them, and then add them programmatically to your form.)